# Spring ReactiveMongoRepository bean not generated

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb

I am quite new to Java & Spring and this is my first Kotlin app so my problem could be Layer-8 (me). But I really do not know what I make wrong. According to this tutorial (https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-mongodb-spring-webflux) this should work.

My general app setup is Controller --> Service --> Repository (I did not add the controller since this is not the issue). My problem is that the Repository Bean can not be created by the factory.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'driveController' defined in file [/Users/sburger/Documents/Dev/Gravity/App Framework/bouncr/build/classes/kotlin/main/de/example/drive/controller/DriveController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'driveService' defined in file [/Users/sburger/Documents/Dev/Gravity/App Framework/bouncr/build/classes/kotlin/main/de/example/drive/service/DriveService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IBookingsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:67) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at de.example.AppKt.main(App.kt:14) ~[main/:na]
    at de.example.AppKt.main(App.kt) ~[main/:na]
```

**App.kt**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration::class])
open class App

fun main() {
    runApplication<App>()
}
```

**MongoConfig.kt**

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = [IBookingsRepository::class])
open class MongoConfig : AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration() {
    override fun getDatabaseName() = "exampledb"

    override fun reactiveMongoClient() = mongoClient()

    @Bean
    override fun reactiveMongoTemplate() = ReactiveMongoTemplate(mongoClient(), databaseName)

    @Bean
    open fun mongoClient(): MongoClient = MongoClients.create()

}
```

I had to mark the class and fun as "open". Without it the build did not work. This is already different to the tutorial.

**DriveService.kt**

```
interface IDriveService {
    fun getBookings(userId: String) : Flux<Booking>
}

@Service
class DriveService @Autowired constructor(private val bookingsRepository: IBookingsRepository) :
    IBookingService {
    override fun getBookings(userId: String): Flux<Booking> {
       return bookingsRepository.findAll()
    }
}
```

The "findAll()" method is inherited from ReactiveMongoRepository

**BookingsRepository.kt**

```
interface IBookingsRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<Booking, String>
```

This interface has obviously no init function, but in the tutorial it also has none. So I assume it should work as it is?

Has someone a hint what could be wrong with this setup?

Comment: Why did you exclude the auto-configuration? Spring Boot will auto configure all of that for you.

Comment: Also please post the full exception instead of just a snippet.

Comment: The stacktrace is pretty clear. At least `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses` should give you a hint on what is wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your quick response. Actually I am not sure. I checked the source code of this tutorial (https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-5-data-reactive/src/main/kotlin/com/baeldung/Application.kt) an they have done it as well.

If I remove it I get this error

The bean 'reactiveMongoTemplate', defined in class path resource [.../mongo/MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [.../config/MongoConfig.class] and overriding is disabled.

Comment: Ok, I had to add "kotlin-reflect" as a dependency. I still have a problem but at least I am a step further. Thanks @M.Deinum

Comment: You shouldn't use `MongoConfig` but use auto-config.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here:

1. You need to add a dependency to `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect`.  If you generate a Kotlin project at `https://start.spring.io/`, it should be added automatically.
2. That Baeldung tutorial is bad.  They exclude auto-configuration for
   no reason, or at least not explaining why.  Spring Boot is all about
   [Convention Over Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) so the default should be to use
   as much of the auto-configuration as possible.
3. As you noted in your comments, not excluding auto-configuration causes an exception.  This is due to a bug in Spring Data MongoDb for which ticket [DATAMONGO-2355](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2355) was recently opened as a result of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761228).
4. The proper solution in this case however, is not to exclude auto-configuration, but to make even more use of it.  There is no reason to extend `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration` here.  As is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57761411/775138), you can configure the DB name through a property and leave all else auto-configured.  Should you need to extend `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration` for some reason, until the bug is fixed you can override the `reactiveMongoTemplate()` method to narrow the return type to `ReactiveMongoTemplate` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57768124/775138).