# Spring Boot 2.1 duplicate reactiveMongoTemplate bean

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following Spring Boot `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
class MongoConfiguration : AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration()
{
    override fun reactiveMongoClient() = MongoClients.create()

    override fun getDatabaseName() = "mydb"

    override fun customConversions(): MongoCustomConversions =
            MongoCustomConversions(listOf(ZonedDateTimeReadConverter(), ZonedDateTimeWriteConverter()))
}
```

The application fails to start, and logs this message:

> The bean 'reactiveMongoTemplate', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/mypackage/MongoConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

This puzzles me, as the `reactiveMongoTemplate` ben method in `MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration` is configured with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration` that you have sub-classed. The signature of its `reactiveMongoTemplate` `@Bean` method states that it returns `ReactiveMongoOperations`. Until the bean has been created, that's all the type information that is available and there is no way for the bean factory to know that the bean is actually a `ReactiveMongoTemplate` instance. As a result, the `@ConditionaOnMissingBean` that's looking for a `ReactiveMongoTemplate` bean doesn't find one so an attempt to define both beans is made. This should be fixed in Spring Data MongoDB so that `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration` provides as much type information as possible for its beans. I've opened [DATAMONGO-2355](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2355).

You can avoid the problem by making more use of Spring Boot's auto-configuration. Rather than sub-classing `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration` you can:

1. Use the configuration property `spring.data.mongodb.database=mydb` to set the database.
2. Use the auto-configured `MongoClient` bean rather than defining your own.
3. Define your own `MongoCustomConversions` bean that will then be used in favour of one that Boot would otherwise auto-configure.

Comment: I guess they could also just specify the ‘ReactiveMongoOperations‘ either in the ‘ConditionalOnMissingBean‘ annotation or as the return type for the method in ‘MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration‘.

Comment: See my answer for a different fix.  I agree though that using more of the auto-configuration is better, and that the root cause must be fixed in Spring Data MongoDb itself.

Comment: BTW it turns out I don't even need the custom conversions.  One should use `Instant` in the data model as the original timezone is lost anyway when converted `java.util.Date` and stored in MongoDb in UTC :)

Answer (score 0):

As Andy's answer correctly points out, there is a mismatch between the return type of `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration#reactiveMongoTemplate` and the autoconfigured bean: the first one is `ReactiveMongoOperations` while the second one is `ReactiveMongoTemplate`.  And as this happens to be the only type info available to the bean factory, the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` has no effect.

So the problem goes away if I simply override `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration#reactiveMongoTemplate` to narrow the return type like this:

```
override fun reactiveMongoTemplate(): ReactiveMongoTemplate = 
        super.reactiveMongoTemplate() as ReactiveMongoTemplate
```

This is a hack though: the autoconfiguration should back out when any `ReactiveMongoOperations` bean is configured (for example, a stub).

So contrary to what Andy says, I believe the problem is not in `AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration` but in `MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration` where the `reactiveMongoTemplate` bean method should be annotated with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ReactiveMongoOperations.class)`.

This was probably forgotten because normally the actual bean will be a `ReactiveMongoTemplate`.  But why have the `ReactiveMongoOperations` interface at all if it's not supported properly?